# Ubuntu 20.04 Cannot find Ksplice Uptrack information for your kernel version

Tags: kernel

I'm running the latest Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and trying to get ksplice working as described [here](https://ksplice.oracle.com/try/desktop). Kernel version 5.4.0-77-generic

I downloaded and installed the .deb file and accept the terms of service but then I get this:

```
Requesting access key... (this may take a few moments)
Access key successfully requested
/usr/sbin/uptrack-upgrade:808: DeprecationWarning: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN will be required for '#' formats
  c.perform()
Cannot find Ksplice Uptrack information for your kernel version
(5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 02:35:03 UTC 2021).
Your kernel is probably not yet supported by Ksplice Uptrack.
See http://www.ksplice.com/uptrack/supported-kernels for a summary of
what kernels are supported.
Please contact ksplice-support_ww@oracle.com with questions.
```

I went to the webpage listed but of course it is broken. Just wanted to post here to see if anyone has any ideas before I email ksplice support.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I recall that would happen if you don't run the default distro kernel (from Ubuntu HWE stack etc), but a specific different kernel release.
The other thing I notice is that it almost sounds (by the string `#86-Ubuntu`) like a 32bit kernel instead of a 64bit kernel, which would be the norm nowadays. I'm not certain they do deliver any updates for 32bit kernels since that is a very rare scenario.

The `DeprecationWarning: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN` also appears for me on an Ubuntu 20.04 system while installing uptrack.

(For context: I used ksplice on ubuntu desktop when working in a SLA-driven Ops team where rebooting your desktop was something you planned days ahead. Likely that was back on Ubuntu 12 or 14, but even then it was a 64bit kernel)